# How to configure multiple sub-domain in nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, server

I want to add sub-domains to my website which is hosted on `nginx`. For this I've added the sub-domain name to the `nginx.conf` file. But whenever I try to access the sub-domain outside localhost it redirects me to the `http://id.domain-error.com/noresult.php`.

Here's my `nginx.conf` file:

```
http {

    server {
    listen 80; # Incoming port for Nginx
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
           root /usr/share/nginx/example;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
    }
    server {
    listen 80; # Incoming port for Nginx
    server_name hello.example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
           root /usr/share/nginx/some_other_example;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Have you added them to DNS?

Comment: That was the error. Totally forgot to add it. Just added `*.example.com` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Alexey, I needed to add the sub-domain in the DNS-configuration. I simply added a wildcard notation `*.example.com` and it started to work.